# What is deps="low" on Travis

Tags: symfony, travis-ci

I have been google this for hours, could someone please tell me what's the meaning of `deps="low"` env var on a Travis-CI Build ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It essentially tells composer to update to the lowest possible version that still meets dependency requirements.

Check this: http://evertpot.com/testing-composer-prefer-lowest/

also, in Travis.yml:

```
- if [ "$deps" = "no" ]; then composer --prefer-source install; fi;
- if [ "$deps" = "high" ]; then composer --prefer-source update; fi;
- if [ "$deps" = "low" ]; then composer --prefer-source --prefer-lowest --prefer-stable update; fi;
```